# Как отключить RTL в xml Android?

Tags: android

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="@color/transparent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/subtitlePanel"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleLeftButton"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_24dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:text="textsd"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtitleRightButton"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_24dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Если менять язык на арабский то меняется стрелка которая смотрит в право. Тобишь она смотрит влево.

Можно ли в Android в XML каким нибудь параметром сказать чтобы при смене языка RTL в ImageButton не менять. Что то типо RTL disable. Мне надо чтобы именно эта View не реагировала на смену RTL ImageButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно отключить для всего приложения в AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:supportsRtl="false">
```

если `ic_keyboard_arrow_right_24dp` - векторное изображение, то можно сменить (API 19+):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="false" <-- эта строка
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    ...
</vector>
```

так же можно использовать папки:

```
drawable-ldltr // LTR
drawable-ldrtl // RTL
```

Comment: android:autoMirrored с 21 апи. Надо с 17 хотя бы.

Comment: а изображение векторное? потому что на апи < 21 векторные подключаются через `app:srcCompat`. для растрового можно в `drawable-ldrtl` положить нужное

Comment: векторное______

Comment: Короче я правильно вас понял или использовать API 19 android:autoMirrored.

Или же использовать картинки для RTL drawable-ldrtl?

Comment: я бы использовал оба подхода